# What is the best way to explode a string with simple markup into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, tags, explode

In PHP, and I want figure out the best way to take string that contains some simple tags in it, and explode it into a multidimensional array with each index containing two more arrays with items `tags` and `text`. If no exceptional tags, `tags` would be `null`. If one (or more) tags exist on a section of the string, `tags` would contain a space delimited list of all pertinent tag indicators.

Example:

String

`The __**quick** brown__ fox jumped __over the__ lazy dog.`

Processed Array

```
[
    [
        'tags' => null,
        'text' => 'The ',
    ],
    [
        'tags' => '__ **',
        'text' => 'quick',
    ],
    [
        'tags' => '__',
        'text' => ' brown',
    ],
    [
        'tags' => null,
        'text' => ' fox jumped ',
    ],
    [
        'tags' => '__',
        'text' => 'over the',
    ],
    [
        'tags' => null,
        'text' => ' lazy dog.',
    ],
]
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around what is the best way to go about doing this. The concept seems simple enough, but the more I think about it, the more confused I get about how to carry this out. Is using some combination of the `preg_match` function within a `foreach` the best way to go, or is there some alternative? Any help being pointed in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want the results to be? Have you tried `explode()`?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a **tokenizer**. Imagine having output like this: `[ [ "text", "The " ], [ "tag", "__" ], [ "tag", "**" ], [ "text", "quick" ], [ "tag", "**" ], [ "text", " brown" ] .. etc` (a little condensed because I don't have much space here). I don't know if regular expressions are the best tool here. I think it's enough to do a loop over the string to find each _tag_. Each token is a tuple of ( text|tag, [value] ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have imbricated markups, you'll need a stack to keep track of the imbrication levels. There's no way to do that directly with regular expressions, so it's probably easier to just iterate on the string symbols.

As a start:

```
print_r(process("The __**quick** brown__ fox jumped __over the__ lazy dog."));

function process($str) {
  $str = '~~'.$str.'~~';
  $sz = strlen($str);

  $res = array();
  $stack = array();
  $text = '';

  for($n = 0; $n < $sz; $n++) {
    if(strpos('*_~', $c = $str[$n]) === false) {
      $text .= $c;
      continue;
    }
    if($text) {
      $res[] = array('text' => $text, 'tags' => implode(" ", array_slice($stack, 1)));
      $text = '';
    }
    $c .= $str[$n++];
    $c == end($stack) ? array_pop($stack) : $stack[] = $c;
  }
  return $res;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => The
            [tags] =>
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => quick
            [tags] => __ **
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] =>  brown
            [tags] => __
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] =>  fox jumped
            [tags] =>
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [text] => over the
            [tags] => __
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [text] =>  lazy dog.
            [tags] =>
        )
)
```

Some notes:

- This code assumes that the input is correct. It doesn't perform any check.
- Internally, the whole string is encapsulated into '~~' markups. This way, the string processing ends with the 'end of tag' condition and the last pending block of text is correctly appended to the result set. (Call me the lazy dog for doing it like that.) This markup is however not injected in the final result.

Answer (score 0):

The devil is not so black as he is painted.

```
$str = 'The __**quick** brown__ fox jumped __over the__ lazy dog.';

$t = array_map(function($i) { 
     $i = preg_split('/[^ A-Za-z]+\K/', $i,2); 
     if (count($i) == 1) array_unshift($i, null);
     return $i;
     },  preg_split('/[A-Za-z.,]\K(?=[^A-Za-z.,])/', $str));   
print_r($t);
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/607941)**